# What subfloor should I use in the bathroom for LVT?

Tags: subfloor, vinyl-flooring

I need to fit [Luxury Vinyl Flooring](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Novocore-Natural-Oak-Luxury-Vinyl-Flooring---1-98m2/p/236753) throughout the top floor of my house, however the floorboards in the bathroom are all at different heights. I know that LVT requires an absolutely flat surface, so what is the best solution for this?

I have seen others replace all the floorboards with chipboard sheets. Is that permissible in a bathroom? Would plywood or OSB be better?

I am in England if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: plywood would be a waste of money. you can use self-leveling cement. or just raise up the low spots. "absolutely flat" is a bit overstated; a few mm won't hurt anything, especially on non-traffic areas like behind the toilet.

Comment: There are too many gaps between the floor boards for self levelling cement

Comment: you can flex seal the cracks, but boards might be better for all involved.